# How to use join properly when i want to get a specific row in another column

Tags: php, mysqli, backend

I have two columns, one of them is (users) and the other one is (user_messages).
Now, I want to get just the users which has then name "unreaden" inside (user_messages).

```
$user="select * from users LEFT OUTER JOIN user_messages.msg_seen='unreaden' ON users.id=user_messages.m_id";
```

After that just count them and put the amount of them next to username in brauser with the help of mysqli num_rows. After the query when I check it, it gives me boolean (false). I think the problem is with the query. Can you check if there is an error with my code on joins?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution should look something like this.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$query = "select users.name as user_name, count(user_messages.id) as no_of_unread_messages "
        ." from users LEFT OUTER JOIN user_messages ON ( users.id = user_messages.user_id AND user_messages.msg_seen='unreaden')";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo $row["user_name"]." ". $row["no_of_unread_messages"];

    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```